# make height of colour bar match the height of the main plot in R/ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

here is a reprex

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
dat <- iris[,1:4]
cor <- melt(cor(dat, use="p"))
head(cor)
heat <- ggplot(data=cor, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) 
heat + geom_tile() + labs(x = "", y = "") + scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-1, 1))
```

[image]

how can I make the color bar height match and align with the y-axis?

many thanks!

Comment: very interesting question. I think I might put a bounty on the linked duplicate - keep your eyes peeled.

Comment: Myriad - I have added a solution to this question in my answer to the linked duplicate as an example.

Comment: thank you both, I will delete this question now

Comment: Myriad, please don't delete this question!! Duplicates are good! They help people finding good answers - it increases the searchability and visibility of relevant threads. And you have asked a very good question!

Comment: Ahh sounds good..thanks @tjebo will keep it